# Transfer CSV data to Oracle table by Column or fields using Talend

Tags: oracle, talend

I am using Talend Studio with objects 
tFileInputDelimited row1(Main) to tOracleOutput
what I want is to transfer the data in CSV file which are
cell delimited (looks like an excel record) to Oracle table
but after execution the rows are inserted on one column only in oracle table .
[image]

what is the proper settings in tFileInputDelimited , or do I need to use other tools?

Image below is the structure of my CSV File.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, open your csv file in notepad(++ preferably) in order to see its column separator. Then define the separator in `tFileInputDelimited > Basic settings > Field separator`, and define the schema of the file using Edit schema button (individual file columns).
If you keep this job design, your file needs to have exactly the same schema as your Oracle table (same column names and types). For more flexibility, you can add a `tMap` between the two, so that you could map the columns differently or do any necessary transformations.

Comment: great! Thanks a lot